# Generate random colour onclick [Android Studio]

Tags: android, random

Im trying to set a random colour in app with AndroidStudio, this is my code:

```
 } else if (check.equals("random")) {
                display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011));
```

How I can do when the user click set random colour? Now is showing 184, 134, 011

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
display.setTextColor(color);
```

Comment: Ok, so now how I can insert it inside: 
                } else if (check.equals("random")) {
                    display.setTextColor());
?

Comment: All works correctly! thanks a lot :D